# aes_encrypt in MySql without using aes_encrypt in the sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to do

```
select name, lower(hex(aes_encrypt(name,'mykey'))) as encValue from myTable;
```

without using the part

`lower(hex(aes_encrypt(name,'mykey'))) as encValue` in the sql statement.

How can I do this? Can I somehow do the encrypting somewhere else, and still have it returned with the results? Maybe in a function? I'm doing this just to be on the safer side in case safety is compromised.

So my results will be:

```
name | encValue
me   | s63gd7dnd8dm
```

Comment: What threats are you trying to defend against?  Why do you not want to use `AES_ENCRYPT()`?

Comment: I never said I did not want to use aes_encrypt. I said I don't want to use it in the sql.

Comment: I'm confused... Why don't you just encrypt in your app?

Comment: Okay, fine.. I shall reword.  Why do you not want to use `AES_ENCRYPT()` "*in the SQL*"?

Comment: To keep code clean. My sqls are massive. Then comes the security part. If someone got to my code, they wont be able to see how it's being done.

Comment: @jmenezes: "[*security through obscurity is an illusion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION EncryptName(name VARCHAR(50)) -- use the same type as myTable.name
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
RETURN LOWER(HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(name,'mykey')));
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
SELECT name, EncryptName(name) as encValue FROM myTable;
```

Make sure to protect this function definition from unwanted access. You are moving the security concern from the application layer to the database layer.

You may also create a view so as to mask even further the encryption process:

```
CREATE VIEW EncryptedView AS
SELECT name, LOWER(HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(name,'mykey'))) AS encValue FROM myTable;
```

Then you can use it as a regular table: `SELECT * FROM EncryptedView`. The same security concerns apply to the view definition.

Comment: Can I use a function in an sql statement? Say: `select name, call function() from table`. Can something like that be done?